# Вывести в корзине рекомендуемые товары к текущему товару

Tags: php, битрикс

**Доброго времени суток.**
Пытаюсь вывести в модальном окне корзины вывести рекомендуемые товары к выбранному товару.
в basket_items.php, подключаю компонент bitrix:catalog.recommended.products, и его вид recommended-prods-basket
Например у ноутбука есть множественное свойство RELATED_PRODUCT в котором подключаются несколько рекомендуемых товаров. Как мне вывести рекомендуемые товары? . Задумка заключается в том что рекомендуемые товары будут крутится в низу в owl carousel.

Я указал в компоненте свойство "OFFERS_PROPERTY_LINK" => "RELATED_PRODUCT", "PROPERTY_LINK" => "RELATED_PRODUCT"
Но все равно товары не отображаются. В массиве $arResult только выбранные товары, т.е. те что были добавлены в корзину.
Подскажите пожалуйста как вывести все рекомендуемые товары?

Comment: Если свойство RELATED, почему вы выбираете RELATED_PRODUCT?

Comment: Alexey Kapustsin Я его переименовал на RELATED_PRODUCT

Comment: @Dolphin странно, что в `В массиве $arResult только выбранные товары, т.е. те что были добавлены в корзину`, в $arResult шаблона bitrix:catalog.recommended.products? а вот `"OFFERS_PROPERTY_LINK" => "RELATED_PRODUCT"` лишнее, так как вы в свойстве RELATED_PRODUCT связываете товары (если правильно понял)